Can internal force accelerate the center of mass?
(Ambiguity about Internal work, internal forces, the kinetic energy of the centre of mass) Excuse me, I was taught that the centre of mass can only accelerate if there is a net external force acting on it. But in the case of a moving car, the net external force is friction. (which due to instantaneous point of contact we can say does not work, or at least, it does negative work). So the work that accelerates the car comes from internal work, caused by fuel combustion. Internal work is due to internal forces. So internal FORCE causes acceleration of the center of mass. But we know this statement is wrong. So how? The same question applies to a rocket in space. (Though in that case due to the release of fuel and mass, I think the rocket accelerates but the motion centre of mass (fuel and rocket's body), remains unchanged. Would someone, please clarify this paradox? This PDF made me more confused https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/003/12/0069-0077
Edit: I appreciate all the answers. They clarified many misconceptions I had learned. Thank you everyone

It stops being an internal force when you either a) consider things like external friction which are the real force at hand (not internal) or b) eject something from your rocket, since the exhaust flying out of the reaction chamber puts a lot of force on the chamber (there, the exhaust becomes external to the system).

A car suspended in midair can't accelerate without touching the ground - an external force is needed. For a rocket to push off its exhaust, we need to either consider the exhaust to be external to the system (in which case the 3rd law reaction force is external), or we consider the exhaust as part of the system, in which case the CoM doesn't move anywhere at all.

It appears the root of your paradox is the belief that an external force needs to do work in order to enable the acceleration of the COM of an object. But that is not always the case when the conversion of potential energy to kinetic energy is involved.
Although the static friction force the Earth applies to the car does no work on (transfers no energy to) the car, there is an exchange of linear momentum between them (though the motion of the Earth is infinitesimal due to its huge mass relative to the car) for conservation of momentum of the isolated Earth-car system. Thus there is no acceleration of the COM of the Earth-car (isolated) system due to the "internal" static friction forces in the system. Moreover, the increase in kinetic energy (KE) of the car is due to the conversion of the chemical potential energy of its fuel.
In addition to the Rocket-fuel example, another is that of an ice skater pushing off a wall and acquiring kinetic energy. While the wall provides the equal and opposite force per Newton's 3rd law enabling the skater to accelerate (like the kinetic friction force between the Earth and the car), it does no work on (transfers no energy to) the skater, since there is no displacement of the skaters hands while they are in contact with the wall.
There is, however, an exchange of momentum between the skater and the Earth (to which the wall is attached), so that there is no acceleration of the COM of the Earth-skater system. The kinetic energy acquired by the skater comes from the chemical potential energy of the skaters cells (the skater's "fuel").
Bottom line: There is no paradox when you consider the internal forces to be those associated with the above Earth-car, Earth-skater, or Rocket-fuel systems and that external forces can enable acceleration without doing work because the acquired KE is the result of the conversion of some form of potential energy.
Hope this helps.

There's a bit of confusion here. As an example

so the work that accelerates...

is conceptually wrong. In general, work doesn't accelerate anything, external forces do.
Physical principles and governing equations. Net external force makes the center of mass accelerate, following the 2-nd principle of Newton mechanics,
$$\dot{\mathbf{Q}} = \mathbf{F}^e \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{Q} = m \mathbf{v}_G$ the momentum of the system, $m$ its mass, and $\mathbf{v}_G$ the velocity of the center of mass.
Internal forces have no influence at all, since they're self-equilibrated, for the 3-rd principle, action/reaction principle.
Time derivative of the kinetic energy of a system equals the total power acting on the system, coming both from internal and external actions,
$$\dot{K} = P^{tot} =P^e + P^i \ .$$
Your examples: car. In the example about the car, the engine provides power. With the assumption of ideal pure rolling, friction between wheels and ground produces no power on the system, so that all the engine power is transferred to the system, to make it accelerate (if it exceeds negative power produced by aerodynamic drag and street slope if the car travels on a road uphill).
Despite friction introduce no power into the system, it provides the required external force for acceleration and breaking, or just to keep the car at constant motion to contrast aerodynamic drag.
Your examples: rocket. Rocket is an open system, thus you need to take into account even fluxes across the boundary of the system. I answered a question yesterday here, if you want to take a look ad a detailed evaluation.


the centre of mass can only accelerate if there is a net external force acting on it.

Correct.

But in the case of a moving car, the net external force is friction. (which due to instantaneous point of contact we can say does not work, or at least, it does negative work).

It does approximately zero work, and when we take into account rolling resistance, it does negative work.

So the work that accelerates the car comes from internal work, caused by fuel combustion.

"Work accelerates the car" is not a standard expression in mechanics. It is true that internal work has to be performed if we are to see increase of kinetic energy of the car. But this increase could happen without the car accelerating - just lift the car a bit so its wheels do not touch the ground. Internal work of the engine will increase kinetic energy of the wheels and temperature of the car, but acceleration will stay zero.
To change the car acceleration, external force is absolutely needed. However, it is not required that this external force does work. In case of the wheels performing ideal rolling without resistance, the ground does zero work on the wheels, but transfers non-zero momentum to them, which is what matters to acceleration.

Internal work is due to internal forces. So internal FORCE causes acceleration of the center of mass.

In a sense, yes, but only indirectly, if these internal forces first cause external forces to act on the car. If the car is not touching the ground, internal forces will not cause the external forces to act, and the car won't accelerate.
